# Use Conditional Format to automatically highlight active Rows on UsedRange

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I need to automatically highlight active Rows using `Conditional Format`.
The below code works successfully with only **one** active row.
I mean by active rows, the cells which manually selected by using mouse or hold Ctrl button.

```
Sub Highlight_active_Rows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange.Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.count - 2).Offset(2)    '(UsedRange except Two Row)
    
    With rng
      .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ROW()=CELL(""Row"")"
      .FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
      .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 190, 142)
      .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With 
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Me.Range("A1").Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you work with `Selection` and do something like `For Each c in Selection.Cells ... c.EntireRow.ApplyFormatting() ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `CELL("Row")` return the row index of the first cell in selection, so it can not highlight multiple rows

Consider taking a different approach.

- The event code involves conditional formatting in the used range.
- It's possible that there is pre-existing conditional formatting in your file. The new FC temporarily overwrites the original one but reverts after a selection change.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rRow As Range, useRng As Range, oFC As FormatCondition
    ' Get the target range
    Set useRng = Me.UsedRange.Resize(Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2)
    ' Remove the FCs which are created by SelectionChange events
    For Each oFC In useRng.FormatConditions
        If oFC.Formula1 = "=TRUE" Then oFC.Delete
    Next
    ' Get the intersection range
    Set rRow = Application.Intersect(Target.EntireRow, useRng)
    If Not rRow Is Nothing Then
        ' Add new FC
        Set oFC = rRow.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="True")
        With oFC
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = RGB(250, 190, 142)
            .StopIfTrue = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You lost it if you run any VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach - but with the same issue: **Undo-Stack will get lost**.
This is always the case as soon as VBA does some changes within the workbook.

This is not the case with your current implementation as VBA only starts the calculation but does not change anything.

I can't think of a way to do the formatting w/o storing the selected rows somewhere ...

This solution uses the same approach like yours: having a format condition (applied once!) that checks against the selected rows stored in name `sel`.

Within `Worksheet_SelectionChange` selected rows are read and name `sel` is set. No need to apply format conditions with every selection.

```vb
Sub prepareForHighlightActiveRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "sel", 0   'will be used by format condition, value is set in worksheet_selection change

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.UsedRange.Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2)    '(UsedRange except Two Row)

Dim fc As FormatCondition
Set fc = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, _ 
                Formula1:="=ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRUE,ROW()=sel,0))")

With fc
    .Interior.Color = RGB(250, 190, 142)
    .StopIfTrue = False
    .SetFirstPriority
End With

End Sub
```

Format condition checks against the name `sel`

`sel` will be handled within `Worksheet_selectionchange`event:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
  ThisWorkbook.Names("sel").RefersToLocal = getRowNumbersForRange(target)
End Sub
```

Using this function to return the row number of all selected rows - taking care of several areas when selecting with `Ctrl`

```vb
Public Function getRowNumbersForRange(rg As Range) As Variant

Dim a As Range
Dim i As Long
If rg.Areas.Count = 1 Then
    i = rg.Rows.Count
Else
    For Each a In rg.Areas
        i = i + a.Rows.Count
    Next
End If

Dim r As Range, arrRows As Variant
ReDim arrRows(1 To i)

i = 0
For Each a In rg.Areas
    For Each r In a.Rows
        i = i + 1
        arrRows(i) = r.Row
    Next
Next

getRowNumbersForRange = arrRows
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to preserve the elements of `Undo-Stack` before selection_Change and return back afterwards ?

Comment: There is kind of an implentation described here: https://jkp-ads.com/articles/undowithvba00.asp - but it is not bullet proof

Answer (score 1):

This answer makes Excel rather slow, especially for larger sheets. I will add it for completeness because it doesn't affect the Undo stack.

You loose the Undo stack whenever you *modify* anything in an Excel sheet using VBA (calling VBA alone doesn't affect it). So that leaves you with conditional formatting, but with a formula that is put once into the worksheet, not modified dynamical.

Unfortunately, there is no Excel formula that returns the address of the current selection, so we need a small function that checks if a certain cell is within the selected rows. We need to define the function as volatile so that it is recalculate every time a recalculation is triggered.

```
Function isSelectedRow(Target As Range) As Boolean
    Application.Volatile
    ' Using Or Error here to ignore errors if selection is not a Range.
    On Error Resume Next
    isSelectedRow = Not Intersect(Target, Selection.EntireRow) Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Now we add a conditional formatting rule to the sheet, using the formula
`=IsSelectedRow(A2)` (assuming that you have a header row that you don't want to format). Testing the sheet: *Nothing happens...*

The reason is that volatile functions are called whenever a recalculation takes place, but just changing the selection will not trigger a recalculate. Okay, we add the calculation to the Selection_Change event of the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

And now: *Still Nothing happens...*. Why that?
Because calculate will recalculate all formulas, but not the formulas in the conditional formatting. You can force Excel to do so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This seems to trigger the recalculation of the formulas in the conditional formatting (don't think there is any documentation about that). Nice. But painfully slow. The reason is that there is a call from Excel to VBA for every cell, and this is known to be slow.

---

So we should limit the number of calls to VBA. My suggestion is to use a helper column that contains the formula `=IsSelectedRow(A2)` and use that column to calculate the conditional formatting. Assuming that this helper column is column K, the formula for conditional formatting is then simply `=$K2` (don't forget the dollar-sign). However, now we need to trigger recalculation in the change event to force that the helper column is recalculated.

However, this solution comes with a new price tag: Calling `Application.Calculate` will clear your Paste-Buffer (that's the case already in your solution).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to a new module:

```
Public RngSelection As Range
Function Top()
    
    Top = RngSelection.Row
    
End Function
Function Bottom()
    
    Bottom = RngSelection.Row + RngSelection.Rows.Count - 1
    
End Function

Sub Highlight_active_Rows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange.Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2).Offset(2)    '(UsedRange except Two Row)
    
    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
                              Formula1:="=AND(ROW()>=Top(),ROW()<=Bottom())"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(250, 190, 142)
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Add this to the sheet's module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Set RngSelection = Target
    Me.Calculate
    
End Sub
```

Run the `Highlight_active_Rows` subroutine to apply the conditional formatting. The undo stack is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem when implementing this using VBA or the Excel COM interface is losing the undo stack. If you're open to a non-VBA add-in solution, then FormulaDesk Navigator has this feature, called 'Track active cell'. It doesn't alter the workbook in any way, and therefore doesn't affect the undo stack. It accomplishes the visual highlighting by painting over the window. The visual styling of the highlighting can also be customized.

https://www.formuladesk.com/formuladesk-navigator/

*Disclosure: This is my product. Answering because it solves the poster's issue, although not via VBA.*

Answer (score -1):

Since `Cell` formula, for "Row" `info_type` argument returns only the top left cell of a larger selection, you can use it as formula in Conditional Formatting **only for a single row**, as also stated in the first comment.

But, if you only need highlighting the selection, you can also use **only** `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event and two variables to keep the previous selected range. Please, copy the next code in the sheet code module where you like to produce the highlighting:

```
Option Explicit

Private prevSelection As Range, col As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange.Resize(Me.UsedRange.rows.count - 2).Offset(2)) Is Nothing Then
   If prevSelection Is Nothing Then  'first time, when nothing has been selected
      Set prevSelection = Target: col = Target.Interior.Color: Exit Sub
   End If
   prevSelection.Interior.Color = IIf(col <> 0, col, 16777215) 'sometimes in case of multiple selections col becomes zero...
   Set prevSelection = Target   'memorize the selected range for the next selection
   col = Target.Interior.Color  'memorize the selection color, for the next selection
   Target.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 190, 142)
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am afraid to say this approach is away from what I need. there are some issues with it, **(1)** if the selection has already interior color applied then it it will be removed ,**(2)** even if I applied interior color for the selection then it will be also removed after `Selection Change` , **(3)** I need to highlight active rows on used range and not only the selection.